# Drop column in table with 2M records

Tags: sql-server, relational-database, bigdata

What is the best method to drop a column from a table with about 2 million records?

The table contains users data, and I can not lock it for long. I am afraid that a simple DROP COLUMN could be too slow.

I use MS SQL Server 2012 Standard.

Comment: 2,000,000 rows *really* isn't big data. Dropping a column of 2 million rows that don't involve foreign key references takes less than a quarter second here. Backup first.

Answer (score 0):

First clone it and try the drop and see how long it takes.  Also figure out when your system is most lightly used, like at 3AM or something and do it then.

Failing that, if you really must keep a system up 24-7, then this is a different problem.  In that case you need to be able to log transactions and then a way to roll them back into your data.  This can be relatively easy, or hard depending on how complex your system is.  In other words this would be a way to modify a table while it's hot and not loose anything.

(For all I know some of the better data bases might have this feature built in.  You might look for a more capable data base.)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem at one of the client site. Here is what I did, it takes little more work but I found very useful.

1. Create the exact same table for ex: Person_1 (but '_1') at the last to differentiate with original table.
2. Using `IMPORT AND EXPORT WIZARD` transfer the data from original table to new table.
3. Drop the column in the original table.
4. Follow `STEP2` (there will not be one column mapped because you have removed in original table)
5. Check the data are same and you can Drop the table (`Person_1`).